# How to do regex HTML tag replace in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with hundreds of rows with HTML content. Some of the content has HTML like:

```
<span class=heading-2>Directions</span>
```

where "Directions" changes depending on page name.

I need to change all the `<span class=heading-2>` and `</span>` tags to `<h2>` and `</h2>` tags.

I wrote this query to do content changes in the past, but it doesn't work for my current problem because of the ending HTML tag:

```
Update  ContentManager
Set ContentManager.Content = replace(Cast(ContentManager.Content AS NVARCHAR(Max)), 'old text', 'new text')
```

Does anyone know how I could accomplish the span to h2 replacing purely in T-SQL? Everything I found showed I would have to do CLR integration. Thanks!

Comment: That's probably because pure T-SQL doesn't have any support for regular expressions and is generally weak in terms of string manipulation..... that's why there's SQL-CLR!

Comment: Whew, please don't use TSQL for this :)

Comment: @timmerk - Just to confirm, this is a one-time update of tags that are of a specific pattern with few or no exceptions? If some get missed will it be the end of the world or will it simply be a job to go in and manually correct?

Comment: Perhaps the question should more properly be phrased: "How to transform HTML tags in SQL Server?"  Then it should be obvious that this is not a job SQL Server is well suited for and that perhaps you should write a small application to perform the work.  How much effort is that compared to coming up with some contrived SQL expression that only works 95% of the time and causes you headache later?

Comment: @Michael Petito - Suppose that 95% is more than sufficient for a one-time update such as this and that the 5% can be fixed manually? Suppose they told you that 10% was ok? Would you still consider an Html Parsing solution? How do you justify the massive opportunity cost in your time for a one-off solution for something that does not require perfection when there is a solution that sufficient for the job? Not every Html parsing problem absolutely mandates that a full blown Html Parser must be used. One-time updates of specific and constrained markup with an accepted miss rate is a good example.

Comment: @Thomas: What massive opportunity cost?  Writing a small application that reads records from a database one at a time, transforms them using an existing library, and commits them back to the database is trivial.  My point is that the time to write such an application is likely far less than the time it would take you to: come up with a "sufficient" solution using string operations, identify and manually fix the N% of hundreds of records that didn't work, and debug problems down the road caused because you missed a handful of records manually.

Comment: @Michael Petito - It will take significantly more time to write a small app that uses an Html Parser than to write a single query. It took me all of about five minutes to come up with the solution I did and that was in T-SQL! With RG available, it would take even less time and be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed T-SQL does not natively support regular expressions and this is the sort of problem in which regular expressions would be the tool of choice. First, I'll say that the level of complication in the solution depends greatly on how consistent your data is. For example, suppose we search for items with the heading:

```
Select ..
From ...
Where HtmlContent Like '<span class="heading-2">%'
```

This assumes no additional spacing between `span` and `class` as well as no additional spacing after the final double quote before the end bracket. We could write `'%<span%class="heading-2"%>%'` to account for the spaces but that would also find `div` tags marked as `heading-2` in the same content as any span tag. If this later scenario shouldn't happen but you might have varying spaces, then use this revised pattern. Where we will really run into troubles is the closing tag. Suppose our content looks like so:

```
<span class="heading-2"> Foo <span class="heading-3">Bar</span> And Gamma Too</span> .... <span class="heading-4">Fubar Is the right way!</span>...
```

It is not so simple to find the correct closing `span` tag to change to `</h2>`.  You cannot simply find the first `</span>` and change it to `</h2>`. If you knew that you had no nested `span` tags, then you could write a user-defined function that would do it:

```
Create Function ReplaceSpanToH2( @HtmlContent nvarchar(max) )
Returns nvarchar(max)
As
Begin
    Declare @StartPos int
    Declare @EndBracket int

    Set @StartPos = CharIndex('<span class="heading-2">', @HtmlContent)
    If @StartPos = 0
        Return @HtmlContent

    Set @HtmlContent = Replace(@HtmlContent, '<span class="heading-2">', '<h2>')

    -- find next </span>
    Set @StartPos = CharIndex('</span>', @HtmlContent, @StartPos)

    Set @HtmlContent = Stuff(@HtmlContent, @StartPos, 7, '</h2>')
    Return @HtmlContent
End
```

Comment: Please consider revising the line "this is the sort of problem in which regular expressions would be the tool of choice". Regular expressions are ill-suited to parsing HTML or XML. A DOM parser (such as the Html Agility Pack) is a much better choice. Again, that's not supported by T-SQL.

Comment: @TrueWill - For a simple replace such as being requested, which yes is parsing some Html/XML, regular expressions are a far more appropriate tool than T-SQL. For extensive, or in depth parsing of Html, something like the Agility Pack would be more appropriate. However, if all you want to do is find a single tag in a blob of text, an Html parser is likely to be overkill.

Comment: That way lies madness. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @TrueWill - Sorry I disagree. You are ignoring the context of the problem. First, this is a one time update. Second, he wants to do this in a simple SQL statement if possible which knocks the Agility Pack out of the equation. Third, the pattern is somewhat well defined. He might be able to accomplish his goal using T-SQL which in and of itself means that a regex solution would provide even more flexibility. I am well aware the *generally* trying to parse *large* amounts of Html on an ongoing basis using regex is poor choice but that does not fit the parameters of this problem.

Comment: @TrueWill - Perhaps you haven't read the entire article. To wit: "So, while I may attempt to parse HTML using regular expressions in **certain situations**, I go in knowing that:  A It's generally a bad idea.
B. Unless you have discipline and put very strict conditions on what you're doing, matching HTML with regular expressions rapidly devolves into madness, just how Cthulhu likes it..." In this problem, we DO have strict conditions on what is being done and thus using regex is not necessarily a bad choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **positive** that **all** of the HTML is (and will continue to be) valid XHTML and you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, you might be able to cast the columns to an XML data type and use XQuery. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28SQL.90%29.aspx

(Caveat: I haven't tried this.)

I think the best answer, though, is Michael Petito's comment. I would write an application to do this and use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). That will provide a permanent, maintainable solution that will work in nearly all cases.

(If this is a one-shot and you don't care about accuracy, then pick your poison.)

Comment: How can you claim that using regular expressions is "madness" and turn around and suggest parsing Html as XML?! If the Html is not well formed, it will not parse into XML! The odds of this working are orders of magnitude lower if there is even one small problem in the markup than simply using standard search or regex. Sorry, but this is a fragile solution.

Comment: TBH, I'd take back my downvote, if you simply suggested using the Agility Pack as you did your comments. While I think it is overkill, it is a significantly better solution than even attempting to use the XML data type.

Comment: @Thomas: Please note that my answer starts with "**If the HTML is valid XHTML**". The OP didn't mention what the origin of the HTML was. If it's known to be XHTML or well-formed, this may be worth considering. If not, it won't work. In the latter case I would write an application (as Mr. Petito suggested) and use the Html Agility Pack. I've had to maintain 95% solutions and "temporary" quick-and-dirty code that lived on; I'd rather not put others through that.

Comment: @TrueWill - Even if you *thought* it was valid XHTML, one bad record screws the whole update. If you think writing an app using Agility Pack is the right solution then say that *instead* of proposing a solution you clearly know to be bad.

Comment: @TrueWill - If there was even a remote possibility that the solution *would* live on after it was written, then I absolutely agree that an Html parser is the right choice. However, it should be clear that a solution that lives on is not a one-time solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not real strong in SQL Server but here is how I would try to do this:

```
UPDATE TableName SET FieldName = REPLACE(FieldName ,'<span class=heading-2>', '<h2>') SET FieldName = REPLACE(FieldName, '</span>', '</h2>')
```

There might need to be 2 UPDATE statements issued, I am not sure if you can operate on the same field this way. The OP did say ALL occurences of the text. Set me straight if I am missing something.

Of course if there are other `<span class=heading-2>` or `</span>` text that you don't want to change, this won't work.

Answer (score -4):

Gah, use jquery! Don't make life difficult.. there's some sample replace code on the jquery homepage and you can just include the jquery-1.4.2.js in the `<head>` section